# Unable to create v. environment for Python 2.17. Runtime error: failed to query python.exe

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, git-bash, pipenv

Please, help me to resolve this issue.

I attempted to create virtual environment using pipenv --two and failure occured due to runtime error: failed to query python.exe.
Here is a snippet of attempt:

$ pipenv --two
Creating a virtualenv for this project▒
Pipfile: C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\Pipfile
Using C:/users/▒▒▒▒▒▒/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python27/python.exe (2.7.17) to create virtualenv▒
[=== ] Creating virtual environment...RuntimeError: failed to query C:\users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\python.exe with code 1 err: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\virtualenv\discovery\py_info.py", line 471, in \n    print(PythonInfo()._to_json())\n  File "C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\virtualenv\discovery\py_info.py", line 55, in **init**\n    self.prefix = u(abs_path(getattr(sys, "prefix", None)))  # prefix we think\n  File "C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\virtualenv\discovery\py_info.py", line 36, in u\n    return v.decode("utf-8") if isinstance(v, bytes) else v\n  File "C:\users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode\n    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)\nUnicodeDecodeError: \'utf8\' codec can\'t decode byte 0xd1 in position 9: invalid continuation byte\n'

Failed creating virtual environment
pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException:   File "C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException:       return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException:   File "C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 202, in cli
pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException:   File "C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 570, in ensure_project
pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException:   File "C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 505, in ensure_virtualenv
pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException:   File "C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 934, in do_create_virtualenv
pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException:       raise exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException(
pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException:
Failed to create virtual environment.

And here is a snippet of pipenv --support

$ pipenv --support
$ pipenv --support

Pipenv version: `'2018.11.26'`

Pipenv location: `'C:\\Users\\▒▒▒▒▒▒\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\pipenv'`

Python location: `'c:\\users\\▒▒▒▒▒▒\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\python.exe'`

Python installations found:

- `3.8.1`: `C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe`
- `2.7`: `C:\users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\python.exe`

PEP 508 Information:

```
{'implementation_name': 'cpython',
 'implementation_version': '3.8.1',
 'os_name': 'nt',
 'platform_machine': 'AMD64',
 'platform_python_implementation': 'CPython',
 'platform_release': '10',
 'platform_system': 'Windows',
 'platform_version': '10.0.18362',
 'python_full_version': '3.8.1',
 'python_version': '3.8',
 'sys_platform': 'win32'}
```

System environment variables:

- `ACLOCAL_PATH`
- `ALLUSERSPROFILE`
- `APPDATA`
- `COMMONPROGRAMFILES`
- `COMPUTERNAME`
- `COMSPEC`
- `CONFIG_SITE`
- `COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)`
- `COMMONPROGRAMW6432`
- `DISPLAY`
- `DRIVERDATA`
- `EXEPATH`
- `FP_NO_HOST_CHECK`
- `HOME`
- `HOMEDRIVE`
- `HOMEPATH`
- `HOSTNAME`
- `INFOPATH`
- `LANG`
- `LOCALAPPDATA`
- `LOGONSERVER`
- `MANPATH`
- `MINGW_CHOST`
- `MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX`
- `MINGW_PREFIX`
- `MSYSTEM`
- `MSYSTEM_CARCH`
- `MSYSTEM_CHOST`
- `MSYSTEM_PREFIX`
- `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS`
- `OLDPWD`
- `ORIGINAL_PATH`
- `ORIGINAL_TEMP`
- `ORIGINAL_TMP`
- `OS`
- `ONEDRIVE`
- `ONEDRIVECONSUMER`
- `PATH`
- `PATHEXT`
- `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`
- `PLINK_PROTOCOL`
- `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`
- `PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER`
- `PROCESSOR_LEVEL`
- `PROCESSOR_REVISION`
- `PROGRAMFILES`
- `PS1`
- `PSMODULEPATH`
- `PUBLIC`
- `PWD`
- `PROGRAMDATA`
- `PROGRAMFILES(X86)`
- `PROGRAMW6432`
- `SESSIONNAME`
- `SHELL`
- `SHLVL`
- `SSH_ASKPASS`
- `SYSTEMDRIVE`
- `SYSTEMROOT`
- `TEMP`
- `TERM`
- `TMP`
- `TMPDIR`
- `USERDOMAIN`
- `USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE`
- `USERNAME`
- `USERPROFILE`
- `WINDIR`
- `_`
- `CONFIGSETROOT`
- `PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK`
- `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`
- `PIP_SHIMS_BASE_MODULE`
- `PIP_PYTHON_PATH`
- `PYTHONFINDER_IGNORE_UNSUPPORTED`

Pipenv▒specific environment variables:

Debug▒specific environment variables:

- `PATH`: `C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts;C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38;C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl`
- `SHELL`: `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe`
- `LANG`: `ru_RU.UTF-8`
- `PWD`: `C:/Users/▒▒▒▒▒▒/My_Programming/test_project`

---

Contents of `Pipfile` ('C:\Users\▒▒▒▒▒▒\Pipfile'):

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

Comment: Have similar issues related to python3.8 using tox package to create a virtual environment